# Меню под Toolbar. Нет названия табов

Tags: android, material-design, menu, android-toolbar

Пытаюсь сделать так -

[image: Нужно так]

Java код

```
//Pager
    TabsViewPagerAdapter adapter = new TabsViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment1(), "Первый");
    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment2(), "Second");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Set tabs
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Так же вот вам мой класс -

```
public class PagerAdapterHelper extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

public PagerAdapterHelper(FragmentManager manager) {
    super(manager);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
}


@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "ONE";
        case 1:
            return "TWO";
        default:
            return "WTF";
    }
}
```

}

После запуска Активити есть тулбар и поле под ним, но почему-то самих табов на нем нет. Так же сами фрагменты спокойно отображаются/листаются. На табы можно тыкать, все норм, только надписей нет(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для этого применяются табы.

Код разметки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorLightGray">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="scrollable" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appBar"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Код добавления:

```
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        assert toolbar != null;
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

        TabsViewPagerAdapter adapter = new TabsViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
adapter.addFragment(new Fragment1(), "ssss");
adapter.addFragment(new Fragment2(), "Second");
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
assert tabLayout != null;
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setText("1");
tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setText("2");
```

Код адаптера:

```
public class TabsViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public TabsViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Что такое YourFragment и как его сделать?

Comment: @MrKlonwar, это твои 2 фрагмента, которые ты будешь отображать в табах.

Comment: Ошибок больше нет, но при запуске активити почему-то табы не появляются, просто пустая зеленая строчка

Comment: в адаптер добавь метод - 

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

Comment: После добавления метода ничего не изменилось( Сам фрагмент он добавляет, а табы нет

Comment: Причем все нормально листается. Как я понял - не заработало это  
    `assert tabLayout != null;
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);`    
Значит - либо проблемы с методом, либо отчего-то tabLayout стал == null, так? Я склоняюсь ко второму. `TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.editTabs);`, его id - `android:id="@+id/editTabs"`

Comment: Проверил, tabLayout != null - верно. Значит.. С этим методом что-то не то( `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);`

Comment: Ага, еще кое-что нашел. Табы есть, нет надписей на них

Comment: Надписей скорей всего не было из-за того, что метода не было, который я выше в комментах написал. Попробуй сделать cleanProject и запустить заново. @MrKlonwar

Comment: Не помогло, все равно нет надписей. Мой метод - `@Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }` @NikotinN

Answer (score 7):

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

**activity_pull_to_refresh.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

**TabLayoutActivity.class**

```
public class TabLayoutActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pull_to_refresh);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }

        viewPager.setAdapter(new SectionPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    public class SectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new FirstTabFragment();
                case 1:
                default:
                    return new SecondTabFragment();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "First Tab";
                case 1:
                default:
                    return "Second Tab";
            }
        }
    }

}
```